# If $\mathbf{P}(X_n\geq a\;i.o.) = 1$ then does $\limsup_{n\to \infty}X_n \geq a$ almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This may be trivially true (if so let me know). Here is my attempt at trying to prove that this is true, but I am not sure about its validity:

Since $\mathbf{P}(X_n\geq a\;,i.o.) = 1$, then this implies that $\mathbf{P}(X_n\lt a\; ,almost\,always) = 0$.

Now if the set $\Omega_0$ on which $\limsup_{n\to \infty}X_n \geq a$ has $\mathbf{P}(\Omega_0)<1$, then then that means that $\exists$ a set $E\subset \Omega$ with $\mathbf{P}(E)>0$ such that $\forall \omega\in E\quad\exists N$ such that $X_n(\omega)<a,\;\forall n>N$

$\implies$ $\mathbf{P}(X_n\lt a\; ,almost\,always) > 0$, a contradiction.

Therefore, $\limsup_{n\to \infty}X_n \geq a$ almost surely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, firstly, when you fix $\omega \in \Omega$ you cannot say $\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega)$ is not $\ge a$ almost surely, because when fixing $\omega$ you now have a deterministic sequence (not random anymore).

How I would go about this: $\mathbb P( X_n \ge a \ (i.o)) = 1$ means there exist a set $\Omega_0 \subset \Omega$ such that $\mathbb P(\Omega_0) =1$ and for every $\omega \in \Omega_0$ and every $N \in \mathbb N$ you have an $n(\omega,N) \in \mathbb N$, $n(\omega,N) > N$ such that $X_{n(\omega,N)}(\omega) \ge a$. That means, for any $\omega \in \Omega_0$, there exists a subsequence $(n_k(\omega))_{k \in \mathbb N}$, such that $X_{n_k(\omega)}(\omega) \ge a$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$. But as you should know, limsup of sequence is greater or equal to limsup of any subsequence, so we have (for fixed $\omega \in \Omega_0$), that $\limsup_{n \to \infty}X_n(\omega) \ge \limsup_{k \to \infty}X_{n_k(\omega)}(\omega) \ge a$. So we've showed that for every $\omega \in \Omega_0$ it holds, so it holds for a set of measure $1$ and that is the definition of almost sure.

But now a bit of philosophy: As you see, there's nothing more than a proper use of definition (now as I read what you've written, (despite of the fact you fixed $\omega$ and still talking about almost sure) is very good, too, maybe even better, cause simplier, but I've tried my best to do it without contradiction, just use of everything we know in a proper way. So yep, although the fact can be trivially true for someone who's into Probability theory, there's nothing to be ashamed for, that it isn't trivially true for you. There are many things that are hard for me (and there are other which are hard for someone else, this is natural), so don't bother to ask questions, even if you think they might be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion! I have made the edit to my post.

Answer (score 3):

It is a property of  real sequences that $x_n \geq a$ for in finitely many $n$ implies $\lim \sup x_n \geq a$. Applying this to the sequences  $x_n=X_n(\omega)$ we get the result immediately.

Comment: Why doesnt' that make sense? Isn't $P(X_n < a , almost\,always)$ the probability of the set of $\omega$ that are in all but finitely many subsets $A_n$ of $\Omega$ where $A_n=\{\omega$ such that $X_n(\omega)<a\}$

Comment: Well, I haven't seen any book using that terminology. @user147686

Comment: ah i see. I'm getting this terminology from Rosenthal's "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory". $A_n,\; almost\,always$ is a shorthand for liminf $A_n$

Comment: @user147686 Thanks for the information. This terminology is not found in other books on Probability Theory.

Answer (score 1):

I would just say,

If for almost all $\omega,$ $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$P(X_n(\omega) \geq a) = 1,$$
then
$$P(\limsup X_n(\omega) \geq a) = 1.$$
Thus 
$$ \limsup X_n(\omega) \geq a \quad \text {a.s.}$$